# multiple device registration on Azure IoTHub at once using c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, batch-processing, azure-iot-hub

Below code i'm using to register devices into Azure IoTHub

```
foreach (var deviceId in deviceList)
            {
                        // register device into IoT hub 
                        Device device;
            RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString("connectionString");
                        device = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceId));


                        // send message to iot hub
                         DeviceClient deviceClient;
                        await deviceClient.SendEventAsync("data");                       

            }
```

I want to test for around 15000  devices so `deviceList will have 15000 device ids` .

I have tested this for 100 devices its too slow.
I'm executing this code into mvc application.

> Is there any way to increase the speed of execution using anything
>   like batch or Parallel Foreach or threading ?

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend to read the following documents:

- [Manage your IoT Hub device identities in bulk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-bulk-identity-mgmt#import-devices)
- [Reference - IoT Hub quotas and throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling)

  where:
  *Identity registry operations* (create, retrieve, list, update, delete)
      Free, B1 and S1  =  1.67/sec/unit (100/min/unit)
      B2 and S2 =         1.67/sec/unit (100/min/unit)
      B3 and S3 = 83.33/sec/unit (5000/min/unit)

Comment: how exactly i can tackle this ?

Comment: Based on your code, your scenario is: AddDevice-ConnectDevice-SendEvent-UnconnectDevice using two facing endpoints of the Azure IoT Hub such as the service and device sides. Using a registryManager.ImportDevicesAsync  you can handled in your scenario only the first step such as AddDevice (ImportMode.Create).

Comment: ok m executing this on pageload how to increase execution time for max no ?

Comment: In this case, try to use the REST APIs in the two steps with a reusable client proxy:  PUT - create a device and  POST - sendEvent, that's the minimum workflow to the Azure IoT Hub.

Comment: Also, you should consider to yield this test process into the background long running process.